# Get HttpServerRequest for ServerWebSocket in VertX?

Tags: websocket, vert.x

My problem is simple: I need to get `HttpServerRequest` of connection that triggered websocket handler in VertX? Websocket handler provides me just `ServerWebSocket` and I don't see how I can get the underlying `HttpServerRequest`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public void hadle(ServerWebSocket serverWebSocket) { 
    MultiMap headers = serverWebSocket.headers();
}
```

This should do it.

Comment: Some explanation would be good. At the moment this is in the Low Quality queue

Comment: @BillWoodger Since it's my first (and only for the time) answer here I don't really now how to arrange answers properly and I'll be glad to here any suggestion and/or critics. As for this particular answer I'm not sure what do you mean by "some explanation". Question was "how to get WS headers" and I provided the answer.

Comment: Code vs non-code is measured in some way and below some scrore posts are automatically sent to the Low Quality queue. If you can include, say, an explanation of why this works, or when to use it, or something. Searchers trying to find solutions in the future will benefit by having more idea if it will apply to their situation on not. Well done on a good shot at a bad question, by the way :-)

Answer (score 0):

I don't really see what you are trying to do.

Eighter you're trying to establish a http-connection, then you're using the HttpServerRequest or you're using a websocket connection, then you can write to the socket directly using the write methode.

So I guess you're mixing up two things and should decide if you want to use http connection with request/response or websocket with read/write.

Comment: I need to read headers from the request that _started_ the handshake and before the websocket is opened. This for example, socketio server does as well. I understand what you are saying, but Im not mixing here anything :)

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. So I think you should use a DataHandler first, get the request/headers using that DataHandler and using the ServerWebSocket handler as 2nd Handler after the request is processed. So you should be able to send and receive an http-request and then get the upgrade request for a websocket connection.